Why is standard deviation important when comparing scores across different distributions?
Initial Question:
Let's say you are a manager, and you have to compare the evaluation of two employees, A and B, who work in different departments—Marketing and Sales, respectively.
The evaluation metric for Marketing has a mean of 88 and a standard deviation of 12.
The evaluation metric for Sales has a mean of 70 and a standard deviation of 15.

Employee A scored 90 in Marketing, and Employee B scored 75 in Sales. Who performed better in their respective departments?
My Doubt:
Why can't we just compare $X - \mu$ to see which employee is above the mean by how much? Why do we need to divide by the standard deviation? Could you provide some intuition or instructive examples to help me understand?

You haven’t provided the standard deviation for Marketing (or if you have, it’s not displaying).
By way of example, suppose the standard deviation for Marketing is $1$. The Employee A with their score of $90$ places them $2$ standard deviations above the mean, so very good compared to Employee B who has scored only $\frac13$ of a standard deviation above the mean for Sales.
By working out $\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ for each, you are able to make a like-for-like comparison which accounts for the different values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Sigma(M) = 12 and Sigma(S) = 15 in the OP's post

Please define your quality metric. Quality can be measured in a number of ways and knowing your metric can help us give you a better answer. Standard deviation takes into account the spread, whereas Mean is just one number. To give you a sense intuitively,
Let marketing have 9 employees $M_{1} ... M_{9}$, each with an identical score of 50.
Let sales have 9 employees $S_{1} ... S_{9}$ with scores $10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90$.
Mean in both cases is $50$. But sales has more spread. If you compare any marketing employee with employee $S_{5}$ (who has a score of 50) with mean, they all look the same. However, you can intuitively bin $S_{5}$ as a mid-range performer who is better than some and worse than others. If you work out the standard deviation and bin the sales employees in $1\sigma$, $2\sigma$ etc, you will see this mathematically too.
